# When i try to compile i get "unfinished string near '<eof>'

Tags: lua

Any idea how to fix this?
I'm completely noob in .lua and i'm just translating korean map to english and encountered this and cannot continue until i find a fix.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider adding information in text format instead of image for making it easier to the community help you.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, if some text file (for example, .lua-file) is opened in "text mode", the character `0x1A` (SciTE displays it as `SUB` with dark background color) is considered "magic", its meaning is "end of file".   In other words, all content after `0x1A` is ignored.

If you really need this character inside string literal in a Lua program, you can write `"\026"`

Comment: At which spot do i write that "\026" ?

Comment: In every occurence of `SUB`, for example, `0SUBf)` -> `0\026f)`